# Passing (and executing) a quoted command pipeline as a function argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

Today I encountered something quite strange

I have two scripts:

wrong.sh:

```
execute()
{ 
        ${@}
}

execute "ls -l | less"
```

right.sh:

```
execute()
{ 
        ${@}
}

execute ls -l | less
```

Running `sh wrong.sh` gives the following output:

```
ls: less: No such file or directory
ls: |: No such file or directory
```

While running `sh right.sh` gives me the same thing as running `ls -l | less`

May I know:
(1) While running `sh wrong.sh` will give me that wrong output
(2) How to modify the `execute` function so that running `sh wrong.sh` will gives me the same thing as running `ls -l | less`

Comment: Quote the `$@` like this `"$@"` and don't quote the whole argument because the function will search for a literal `"ls -l | less"` which is a whole string but there is more to it than you're telling us, kindly give the real problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Taking a guess at what you're trying to do checkout this link. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

In your `wrong.sh` invocation, you are trying to run a command with the rather unusual 12 byte long name `ls -l | less` (which might actually exist, say as `/usr/bin/'ls -l | less'`)

If you want to interpret a string as a shell command, the easiest thing to do is:

```
sh -c "$command_as_string"
```

So in your case

```
execute()
{
    sh -c "$1" # no ${@} if you only intend to ever pass a single string
               # or $SHELL -c "$1" if you want the *same* shell as you're calling execute() from
}
```